# How does the "\n" function work with variables?

Tags: python

`Issue #1:`  How could I print a new line after this is printed into another script?

```py
names_file.write(output1, "\n")
```

Comment: Ideally you should ask two questions separately. But for Issue 2, you can just do `if not 3 < len(name_first) < 60 or not 3 < len(name_last) < 60:`

Comment: As above states, stick to the one question, what's wrong with Issue #1? What didn't work? You could just `f'{output1}\n'`, does that work?

Comment: Another tip. You should try to create a minimum working example. Rather than posting several lines of code and marking the one line you need, you should just post the one line. I've never seen `.write()` with 2 parameters, but you can just append two line breaks `\n` to the end of `output1` to get a blank line between each line

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Comment: Also tighten up your use of technical terms.  `"\n"` is simply a string of one character; it is not a function.  It is no more magic than "a" or "\t" (horizontal tab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evan,

Issue #1: Concatenate "\n\n" with the value or write it using a separated write command to have a extra line break

```
names_file.write(output+"\n\n")
```

or

```
names_file.write(output)
names_file.write("\n\n")
```

Issue #2: Sounds very procedural, but I think it's OK.

HTH,

WB::